# What voting system is used in the moderator election?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I've recently voted in the moderator election, and I notice that you can place 3 votes (a 1st, 2nd, and 3rd).

This is seems like something approaching Instant Runoff Voting (IRV), which is a huge improvement from the classical First Past the Post (FPP).

Just out of curiousity, **what voting system do the elections use?**

Comment: [MeekSTV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Meek)

Comment: Also see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8XOZJkozfI

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hello fellow CGPGrey fan!

Comment: @DominatorX: absolutely! I still refer people to his video about The Netherlands to explain where I am from originally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We use a Single Transferable Vote system called [Meek STV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Meek).

Basically you have one vote, but if your 1st choice doesn't get through a round the whole of your vote is transferred to your 2nd choice (and then to your 3rd choice). If your 1st choice does get through then a proportion of your vote gets transferred.

Voting proceeds in rounds until the required number of candidates have reached the threshold.

If your 2nd or 3rd choice has already been eliminated then your vote goes nowhere - which is fine.

Comment: I would like to congratulate Stack Exchange for having a better voting system than my country.

Comment: @DominatorX - they have a better voting system than most countries ;)

Comment: Which is why I spend more time on Stack Exchange than politics. (not really)

Comment: Next to C.G.P. Grey's STV explanation I linked to in a comment on the question, this video shows off the transfers of votes nicely: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLH_w5kHJpA

Answer (score 4):

It is the Single Transferable Vote. It's discussed on a Meta Stack Exchange post in detail:

[How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english)